# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment - more solutions

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know this question has been asked already but I cannot find a suitable answer for my problem among the available solutions. I hope you guys can help me out.

I tried to create two fragments. Fragment01 contains a text view, edit text and button. Fragment02 contains a listview. When a button in Fragment01 is clicked, the string in the edit text of this fragment will be sent to Fragment02. The list in Fragment02 will get this string and add it to the list.

Here is my code:
main_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.example.user.myapplication.Fragment01"/>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.example.user.myapplication.Fragment02"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_01.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Enter Names: "
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/entered_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add To List"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_02.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainScreen.java

```
public class MainScreen extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
    }
}
```

Fragment01.java

```
public class Fragment01 extends Fragment {
private EditText editText;
private Button button;

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false);
    editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.entered_text);
    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment02 fragment02 = new Fragment02();
            fragment02.addNewItem(editText.getText().toString());
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.list, fragment02);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Fragment02.java

```
public class Fragment02 extends ListFragment {
    private ListView list;
    private ArrayList<String>itemsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_02, container, false);
        list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(itemsArrayList.size() > 0)
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1, itemsArrayList));
    }

    public void addNewItem(String item){
        itemsArrayList.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your error more clearly.

Comment: I'm not sure if you forgot to include the closing '</LinearLayout>' tag in all three of your layout files in your question or not

Answer (score 0):

In fragment02.xml, in your ListView change:

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

to

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

A look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) shows this:

> ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single list view. However, if you desire, you can customize the fragment layout by returning your own view hierarchy from onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle). To do this, your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

Give it a shot